# Working copy location of xCode SVN repository

Tags: xcode, svn

Reference version: xCode 4.5.2

In Organizer-Repositories I see for each repository a "Root" folder and one or more folders related to the root. How I can see the working copy location related to each folder?

By right-clicking the folders I see only the link to the help and no options to see the actual location of the directory on my computer.

The reason why I'm asking this is that I added folders in my repository from different locations in my local filesystem. Now I need to find all the locations, remove them and put my working copy in a single directory tree to avoid mixing SVN working copy files with non-versioned files.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xCode-Repositories interface for SVN seems incomplete (as appears from other questions/answers on it).

So I've resolved by removing the repository from xCode interface and re-creating it.

I now use "`xcrun svn ...`" command line interface for all the operations except the simple checkout/commit commands.